# Filter Microsoft Graph Drive Search Results where Modified By is Current User

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm attempting to get Drive results using Microsoft Graph that are filtered by the current user.

This is as far I have gotten, which is return results sorted by last modified date, but it's returning results modified by other users.

I want it to only return results where last modified or preferably modified at all by the current user. Is there a way to do that?

So far, I have tried throwing in {User.Name} around the place, but that hasn't gotten me anywhere

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/search(q='')?$orderby=lastModifiedDateTime desc`

Or is this fruitless, and I should use the insights/used endpoint even though it's in beta?

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/insights/used`

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use the `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/insights/used` to get results where last modified or preferably modified at all by the current user.

But APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph is in preview and are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

For the details, please refer to [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/insights_list_used).

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, you want to filter Drive by last modified date and current user.

In order to get `lastModifiedBy` field, we need to able track changes to the file. Please try following API:

`GET /me/drive/root/delta`

Please note that in OneDrive for Business and SharePoint, delta is only supported on the root folder.It does not apply to subfolders other than root folder.

For more detail, we can refer [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_delta). Unfortunately, there isn’t a perfect solution to solve your case.